# functions nested under a prototype function behave differently

Tags: javascript

Functions nested under a prototype function do not get the this.variables defined for the prototype.

```
var Person, p;

Person = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.getInfo = function() {
  var innerFun;
  innerFun = function() {
    return this.name;
  };
  return "name: " + (innerFun()) + " age: " + this.age;
};

p = new Person('dork', 99);

console.log(p.getInfo());      // name:  age: 99
```

I thought that since every function is an object, **this** would be different within every function definition; but the following code blows away that logic.

```
var getInfo;

getInfo = function() {
  var display;
  this.name = 'dork';
  return display = function() {
    return this.name;
  };
};

console.log(getInfo()());     // dork
```

Is there a logic behind this behaviour or should I just take it as a rule and use call() to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version of `this` behavior:

1. In function invoked as `x.f()`, `this` will be `x`.
   (Note: *invoked* as `x.f()`. It does not matter how and where you define it)
2. In function invoked as `f()`, `this` will be `window`.
3. In function invoked as `x['f']()`, `this` will be <s>`window`</s> `x` (not sure why I thought otherwise)
4. In function invoked as `f.call(x)` or `f.apply(x)`, `this` will be `x`.

Again, the prototype does not matter, if you do

```
var f = p.getInfo;
console.log(f());
```

you will see that only calling style matters.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote was for since this is the correct answer.  In any case, to be more clear, in the OP's second example, `this` is `window` both times it is used. `window.name` is set to 'dork' and then `window.name` is still dork when it is accessed.

Comment: Using *innerFun.call(this)* does give the desired result. So the issue was with it being called in context of window. The rule I am setting in my mind is that if no context is provided during a function call, **this** always refers to the global object.

Comment: Regarding x['f']() being called in context of window, I might need some clarification. I tried **console.log(p['getInfo']())**; and it worked in context of **p**.

Comment: @Alex ok I might be wrong here, disregard number 3 for now while I test it.

Comment: Ok I *am* wrong here. This is weird, but anyway number 3 is other way around. I'll probably read a bit more on that.

Comment: Its would have been more confusing if you had been right. The way I had understood javascript was that x.f is the same as x['f'].

Answer (score 0):

**Summarizing Conclusions**:

> Rule: If no context is used for a function call, the default context is the global window object

```
this.name = 'global';
console.log(p.getInfo());       // name: global age: 99
```

*solution1*

use call/apply

```
return "name: " + (innerFun.call(this)) + ": Age " + this.age;
```

*solution2*

Use **this** for inner functions

```
this.innerFun = function() {
  return this.name;
};
return "name: " + (this.innerFun()) + ": Age " + this.age;
```

*solution3*

```
self = this
innerFun = function() {
  return self.name;
};
```